# Performance issue with simple select query (using indexes) in SQLite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table named 'waveforms' with 525k rows. Each row contain 7 columns. Only the fisrt 5 columns are indexed since I use them in the query.

I have a loop that calls a select query 152 905 times with different inputs. It's taking ~5min to finish, so ~2ms per call or ~500 queries per second (QPS).

I think 500 QPS is a little bit slow for the type of query I'm doing. Is there anything else I can do to improve the performance?

#### python and sqlite version

Python 3.7.5

`print(sqlite3.version)`: 2.6.0

#### machine

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz with 4 CPUs (laptop)

Disk: SK hynix SH920 mSATA 256GB (Avg. 4K-64Thread Mixed IO Speed 108MB/s) [c.f. benchmark](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/5328/SK-hynix-SH920-mSATA-256GB)

RAM: 8GB

#### Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE "waveforms" (
    "sc_id" integer,
    "time"  REAL,
    "XYpos" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "NET"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "simulator" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "CAT"   integer DEFAULT 9,
    "csv_file"  BLOB NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("sc_id") REFERENCES "scs"("id"),
    UNIQUE("sc_id","time","XYpos","NET","simulator")
)
```

#### Index

```
CREATE INDEX "index_waveform" ON "waveforms" (
    "sc_id",
    "time",
    "XYpos",
    "NET",
    "simulator"
)
```

#### explain query plan

```
explain query plan SELECT sc_id, time, XYpos, NET, simulator  FROM waveforms INDEXED BY index_waveform WHERE XYpos="111.95_115.80" AND sc_id=1 AND time=3.98e-09 AND NET="NET_X" AND simulator="simX";
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH TABLE waveforms USING COVERING INDEX index_waveform (XYpos=? AND NET=? AND sc_id=? AND time=? AND simulator=?)
```

#### explain

```
explain SELECT sc_id, time, XYpos, NET, simulator  FROM waveforms INDEXED BY index_waveform WHERE XYpos="111.95_115.80" AND sc_id=1 AND time=3.98e-09 AND NET="NET_X" AND simulator="simX";
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     18    0                    00  Start at 18  
1     OpenRead       1     61730  0     k(6,,,,,,)     02  root=61730 iDb=0; index_waveform
2     Integer        1     1     0                    00  r[1]=1       
3     Real           0     2     0     3.98e-09       00  r[2]=3.98e-09
4     String8        0     3     0     111.95_115.80  00  r[3]='111.95_115.80'
5     String8        0     4     0     NET_X  00  r[4]='NET_X'
6     String8        0     5     0     simX  00  r[5]='simX'
7     SeekGE         1     17    1     5              00  key=r[1..5]  
8       IdxGT          1     17    1     5              00  key=r[1..5]  
9       Column         1     0     6                    00  r[6]=waveforms.sc_id
10      Column         1     1     7                    00  r[7]=waveforms.time
11      RealAffinity   7     0     0                    00               
12      Column         1     2     8                    00  r[8]=waveforms.XYpos
13      Column         1     3     9                    00  r[9]=waveforms.NET
14      Column         1     4     10                   00  r[10]=waveforms.simulator
15      ResultRow      6     5     0                    00  output=r[6..10]
16    Next           1     8     1                    00               
17    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
18    Transaction    0     0     7     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
19    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

#### Some PRAGMAS:

```
Auto Vacuum: None
Automatic IndeX: yes
Foreign Keys: yes
Journal Mode: WAL
Journal Size Limit: -1
Locking Mode: Normal
Max Page Count: 1073741823
Page Size: 4096
Secure Delete: yes
Synchronous: Normal
Temp Store: Default
WAL Auto Checkpoint: 1000
```

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on those columns, a second index on the same ones is pointless, btw.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know unique created index automatically.

Comment: Yup. See the **UNIQUE constraints** section of https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html (I don't see a way of speeding up your queries, btw. Maybe playing with cache size and memory mapping pragmas?)

Comment: I checked from [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-unique-constraint/) and it says nothing. That's why I was ignorant.

Comment: @Shawn I found the "issue". If I left the connection open it finishes in less than 1 min (> 2500 QPS). I read that we should always close the connection after querying but it looks like it's a very expensive operation (opening the connection).

Comment: You were doing that? Yeah... opening a sqlite database is slow; it has to re-parse all the DDL statements in the `sqlite_master` table to understand the structure of the database, closing the db of course destroys the page cache so it has to read everything from disk again, and so on. Better to open once and use that connection throughout the life of your program.

Comment: Yep, a sad mistake. I was reading about db for websites where people say to always close the conn. In my case is for me only, so I guess I can make this exception. Thanks for the tips.